# knockoutJS - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_watcher' of undefined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

When I remove an item from an observableArray, I sometimes get an error on the console, that says:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_watcher' of undefined".

```
var successCallback = function (callback) {
    self.CustomerModel.addresses.remove(function (item) { return item.id() == addressId; });
    self.CustomerModel.addresses.valueHasMutated();
    self.CustomerModel.apply();
    if (callback) {
        callback();
    }
};
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Can you post a more complete version of the code? We need to know where/how these variables are defined.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The variables are defined inside of the viewModel.

Comment: Then let's see the viewModel.

Comment: What does `callback()` do?

Comment: This is just an optional callback.

Comment: What's that property `_watcher`? Are the items of the `observableArray` observables as well? If so, do you have `ko.computed`s that depend on these observables?

Comment: @ManfredSpecht You need to elaborate your question. There are simply too few details here to answer properly. Obviously something is null or undefined, but it's hard to tell what and where when we can't see how your viewmodel works.